# Is something in my code erroring my footer.php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes

So far my footer has always done it. But suddenly it disappeared when I started my site. This is a seperated footer in a wordpress site. Loading is going well, because when I use a different code for my footer, it works. I suspect something is not right in my footer.php, but I don't know what?

I have tried some other pieces of code from other footer.php 's. This worked but could not find the difference between my code and theirs.

This is my footer.php (My active theme is a yoga child theme):

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @package yoga
 */
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--==================== FOOTER====================-->
<?php 
  $yoga_footer_widget_background = get_theme_mod('yoga_footer_widget_background');
   if($yoga_footer_widget_background != '') { ?>
<footer style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url($yoga_footer_widget_background);?>');">
  <?php } else { ?>
<footer> 
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="overlay">
  <!--Start yoga-footer-widget-area-->
  <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'yoga-footer_widget_area' ) ) { ?>
  <div class="yoga-footer-widget-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <?php  dynamic_sidebar( 'yoga-footer_widget_area' ); ?>
        <!-- Contact symbols -->
        <div id="text-4" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 yoga-widget widget_text">     
          <div class="textwidget">
            <a href="# 1"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i><a>
            <a href="#2"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x"></i><a>
            <a href="#3"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i><a>
          </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <!--End yoga-footer-widget-area-->
  </div>
</footer>
<!--Scroll To Top--> 
<a href="#" class="ta_upscr bounceInup animated"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a> 
<!--/Scroll To Top-->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can see the error in my code, and has a solution for it.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that using this footer returns nothing? No errors, and nothing else?

Comment: Also, I see you are including wp_footer() toward the end. Is that overwriting your <footer> section?

Comment: Yes, it returns nothing! No errors etc. And I don't know, I don't think so. You mean I have to close my footer tag earlier or later? @AdamCulp